# rails -v returns 2.3.5 but gem uninstall rails offers to uninstall version 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version

I am trying upgrade Rails.  I am pretty sure that Rails 3.1 is now installed, however my rails apps still have no Gemfile, and rails -v returns 2.3.5.  When I type "gem uninstall rails"  I get:

```
aheine@ubuntu:~/www$ gem uninstall rails

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rails-3.0.9
 2. rails-3.1.0.rc1
 3. rails-3.1.0.rc5
 4. All versions
```

How can I get rid of Rails 2, and make rails 3 the default version to use?

I am using Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: whats the output of `which rails`

Comment: ~/www$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails

Comment: Alright that's the system provided rails which tends to be an old version http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/rails. You should uninstall it so you can use the version provided by rubygems, see my answer for the proper commands.

Comment: You should check out RVM (http://beginrescueend.com/) as a way to deal with this and other gem/ruby versioning problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your running with the system provided Rails, run `apt-get remove rails` and then you may need to make a configuration change so the system can find the proper rails command. So see if that works and then try running `rails -v` if that returns command not found add this line to the beginning of your `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

`export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH`

After that's done open a new shell and try running `rails -v` again.

Comment: rails -v
bash: /usr/bin/rails: No such file or directory

Comment: remove rails worked, but I guess I need to do that configuration change

Comment: Ok check the edit and see if the addition of that line fixes it.

Comment: hm, the output changed to:


The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails

Comment: Remove that line and open a new shell. Run `export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH` and then `which rails`. If that doesn't work then run `ls /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`.

Comment: I think I messed up before.  Adding the line in your first edit seems to have fixed it.

Comment: not sure if this is related to the path stuff we did in .bashrc, but when I do "rails new", it creates all the files, then automatically does a bundle and returns:

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:207: warning: Insecure world writable dir /var/lib/gems/1.8 in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:124:in `initialize': Permission denied - /var/lib/gems/1.8/cache/sprockets-2.0.0.beta.14.gem (Errno::EACCES)  

and a ton of stuff of the form:
 1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/bin/bundle:13

Comment: run `sudo chmod o-w /var/lib/gems/1.8`

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help.  That solved the bundle install problem.  Do you know why a scaffold returns this:   ~/www/testapp$ rails g scaffold Person name:string age:integer
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method `context_class' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sass-rails-3.1.0.rc.6/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:48
 from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'  etc,etc,etc

Comment: Success!  (I think.)  I took sass-rails out of my gemfile completely.  Hopefully that won't come back and bite me.  Thanks man!!!